# Getting all the combinations in a list

Tags: python

lets say I have a list [1,1,1,1].

I want to iterate over all the possible combinations while every index of the list must contain a number from 1 to n.

in other words, i want to make a for loop that will go over all the combinations.

like: [n-35, n-5, 1, n], [1, 1, 1, n], [n, 1, n, n-19]. I hope you get the idea.

does anyone has any idea how to do this?

Comment: Try [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Answer (score 1):

see [itertools.combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement). That should do it.

```
for comb in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1,n+1), 4):
    # comb is (1,1,1,1), then (1,1,1,2), then ...
```

Comment: But this is not what i need, i need a loop that will give me an access to check whatever i want to every combination. this is why i have a list.

Comment: itertools gives you an iterator, that you can iterate over and do whatever logic you want on each iteration. So yes, it is what you need.

Comment: this is what i need! thank you polpak!

Comment: polpak edited, I answered. Feels great to be left out.

Comment: you right i'm sorry, thanks Berserker! i was helped by your comment, i didn't get that it actually letting me to iterate through the combinations. polpak just added the range(1, n+1) that was missed. i guess you deserve the main thank.

Comment: Well the original answer said to use itertools.combinations  which wouldn't allow for repeated items, and didn't have an example so....

Comment: You both really helped me!! :)